# Custom post type title is set by other custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, get-the-title

Im trying to make a small plugin that can produce a team with a trainer. The team is a Custom Post Type and the trainer is a Custom Post Type. When I create a new team, i read all the trainers in a combo-box, where the title of the custom post type ***traener*** is the name of the trainer.

My problem is that when I type in a name for the team in the title box, the slug is created with the last title from the ***traener*** Custom Post Type title.

This is what i have come up with so far when i create the register the Custom Post Type and create the metabox with the trainer and som other infos.

```
global $post;
$title = $post->post_title;
echo "<script>alert ('".$title.")</script>";
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'traener',
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'orderby' => 'post_title', // meta_value',
   'order'   => 'ASC',
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
  if ($my_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
      if ($selectedtrainer == get_the_title()) {
        echo '<option value="'.esc_html( get_the_title() ).'"selected=selected>'.esc_html( get_the_title() ).'</option>';                           
      } else {
        echo '<option value="'.esc_html( get_the_title() ).'">'.esc_html( get_the_title() ).'</option>'; 
      } 
    endwhile; 
  }
wp_reset_postdata();

$post->post_title = $title;
```

Is there any way I can reset the post title from being a post title of the ***traener*** custom post type, so the slug will be based on the ***team*** title

I have tried using the save_post action to manipulate the title with no luck, and it is also not eksactly what i want, because when you use the tabulator the slug is generated in the background (ajax/javascript).

Really hope someone can help me in the right direction

Comment: You are using `traener` instead of `trainer` in your arguments. Could that be a problem? By the way, do not use `wp_reset_query();`. Only `wp_reset_postdata();` is enough.

Comment: Jack Johansson - I have edited the description. Unfortunately it does not help only using wp_reset_postdata();. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that i just have to use

```
$post->post_name
```

instead of

```
$post->post_title
```

because **$post->post_name** holds the slug also the autogenerated if you save as draft without defining a title.

So the code would as follows

```
global $post;
$slug = $post->post_name;
echo "<script>alert ('".$title.")</script>";
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'traener',
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'orderby' => 'post_title', // meta_value',
   'order'   => 'ASC',
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if ($my_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
        if ($selectedtrainer == get_the_title()) {
           echo '<option value="'.esc_html( get_the_title() ).'"selected=selected>'.esc_html( get_the_title() ).'</option>';                           
        } else {
            echo '<option value="'.esc_html( get_the_title() ).'">'.esc_html( get_the_title() ).'</option>'; 
        } 
    endwhile; 
}
wp_reset_postdata();

$post->post_name = $slug;
```

Hope this can be of some use for others.